# Как скрыть все элементы кроме одного?

Tags: javascript

Имею такие элементы

```
<button data-modal="1">1</button>
<button data-modal="1">2</button>

<div class="modal" id="1"></div>
<div class="modal" id="2"></div>
```

По умолчанию у меня все .modal display none, хочу при клике скрывать все modal, а то которое открыл display block Как такое сделать? В jQuery знаю есть `not()` а как в js это сделать?

Comment: `$(".modal:not([id='2'])").hide()` не сработает?

Comment: я так понимаю id задан не верно .. имя id не может быть цыфрой

Comment: Да, айди это я пример просто показал, но не работает почему-то. У меня по умолчанию скрыты все модалки, а сейчас я кликаю на первую и он дает display none второму, а первому ничего

Comment: а зачем скрывать все modal если они и так по-умолчанию display:none? Работайте с тем, которое хотите открыть/закрыть

Comment: модальное окно может быть внутри другого. К тому же, я уже самостоятельно решил

Comment: @MonkeyMutant вообще-то может :)

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе не особо хочется, можешь по-извращаться:

```
Array.from(document.body.children).map(item => item.getAttribute("id") == 1 ? item.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 1") : item.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 0"))
```

1. Для начала нам нужно понять Parent компонент наших элементов.
2. Children нашего элемента ([Element.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children)) нужно переопределить Object to Array:
   [итерируемого объекта](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
3. Потом мы можем пробежать данный элемент ([map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) и найти нужные элементы по Id или другим атрибутам ([Element.getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)).
4. При нахождении ненужного, просто отключаем, например ([opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/opacity))

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, исправил!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function select(id) {
  document.querySelectorAll(`div.modal`).forEach((dialog) => {
    dialog.hidden = !(id == dialog.id);
  });
}

//#region FOR DEMO ONLY
select(document.querySelector(`input[type="radio"][name="modals"]:checked`).value);
document.querySelectorAll(`input[type="radio"][name="modals"]`).forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener(`change`, (event) => {
    select(input.value);
  })
})
//#endregion
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="modals" value="first"> Show first modal<br>
<input type="radio" name="modals" value="second"> Show second modal<br>
<input type="radio" name="modals" value="third"> Show third modal<br>
<input type="radio" name="modals" value="" checked> Hide all<br>
<div id="first" class="modal">First modal</div>
<div id="second" class="modal">Second modal</div>
<div id="third" class="modal">Third modal</div>
```